# Toggling nav icon in browser mobile screen size will make nav-list-items dissapear when readjusting browser screen to large size

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, media-queries

Hello my current issue is that when the page initially loads the navigation works and appears properly when the browser is enlarged, however when readjusting the browser window to a smaller size, toggling the nav menu icon works but however will either

a) readjust the layout in the larger web browser screen if the mobile menu was left open
or
b) navigation items will entirely disappear if the mobile menu was closed

when readjusting the browser window back to the larger screen size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chispot_Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a23422f356.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function toggle_visibility(id) {
               var e = document.getElementById(id);
               if(e.style.display == 'block')
                  e.style.display = 'none';
               else
                  e.style.display = 'block';
            }

            // Trying to figure out toggling visibility issue with navigation when going back to large screen
            // let navi = document.getElementById("nav-list");

            // navi.addEventListener(onresize, toggle_visibility){
            //     display = "block";
            // };

    </script>
</head>
<!-- Hamburger Icon from font awesome -->
<!-- <i class="fas fa-bars"></i> -->
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/Component 1.png" alt="blog spot logo">
            <ul id="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="cafes.html">cafes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="views.html">views</a></li>
                <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="posts.html">posts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="hide">
            <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('nav-list');"><i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg hamburger ham-toggle"></i></a>
        </div>
    </header>
```

I have tried to put display:block property under the appropriate class selector inside the larger media query. Which didn't populate any nav-list-items, I kept the display:flex property because thats how I want the nav-list-items to be formatted in the larger layout.

```
/* general */
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover, a:focus{
    color: black;
}

a .icon:hover{
    color: yellow;
}

.logo{
    width: 12em;
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.main-image{
    height: 80%;
    width: 95%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 1em;
    border-color: #111111;
    border-style: solid;
}

.featured-img{
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    order: 1;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.secondary-featured-article-img{
    height: 75%;
    width: 90%;
    object-fit: cover;
    order: 1;
    padding: .75em;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* Typography */

h1{
    font-size: 8rem;
    text-align: center;
}

h3{
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

h4{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

h5{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.site-intro-body{
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    order: 2;

}

.secondary-featured-article-body{
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

footer{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.side-page-post-title{
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: .25em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.side-page-post-body{
    margin-left: 6em;
    margin-right: 6em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
/* Layout Mobile Screen*/
header{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

header .hamburger{
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    align-content: flex-start;
    /* visibility: hidden;  HIDE WHEN IN MEDIA QUERY */
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 2em;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

#nav-list{
    margin-top: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: row;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}

.nav-list-item{
    margin: .1em;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkgray;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    padding-top: 4em;
}

.site-intro{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5em;
}

.site-intro p{
    column-count: 2;
}

.site-photo{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    order: 1;
}

.article-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.featured-article{
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-top: 2.5em;

}

.featured-article-body{
    width: 100%;
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.secondary-featured-article-section{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.secondary-featured-article{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}

.secondary-featured-article-body{
    width: 95%;
    order: 2;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.secondary-featured-article-border{
    border-bottom: .15em lightgray solid;
}

footer{
    padding-top: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.footer-body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.social-media-icons{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.icon{
    margin-right: .5em;
}

.hide{
    height: 100%;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.side-page-post-body{
    margin-top: 4em;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
}

.article-listings{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.article-listing{
    display: flex;
    height: 45vh;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.article-blog-description{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 90%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    order: 2;
}

.article-listing-image{
    order: 1;
    width: 40%;
    height: 90%;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-items: center;
}

.article-listing-title{
    font-size: 1.75em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.article-listing-body{
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: .9em;
}


/* Layout Large Screen*/
@media screen and (min-width: 760px){

        .main-image{
            height: 75vh;
            width: 90%;
            object-fit: cover;
            border: 1em;
            border-color: #111111;
            border-style: solid;
        }
        .featured-img{
            height: 70vh;
            width: 45%;
            object-fit: cover;
            order: 1;
            padding: 1em;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        .secondary-featured-article-img{
            height: 40vh;
            width: 45%;
            object-fit: cover;
            order: 1;
            padding: .75em;
            background-color: lightgray;
        }

        header{
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom:0;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:space-between;
            align-items:center;
            position: fixed;
        }

        header .hamburger{
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            margin-right: 1em;
            visibility: hidden;  /*HIDE WHEN IN MEDIA QUERY */
        }

        nav{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            padding-left: 2em;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #nav-list{
            margin-top: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: row;
            list-style: none;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            visibility: visible;

        }

        .nav-list-item{
            margin: 1em;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
```

I'm currently using a simple script I had found on css-tricks but am open to alternative suggestions to resolve the problem of wanting to simply hide and show the nav menu without any issues affecting the other layout in the large media query.

Comment: Consider providing a Codepen snippet for your code.

Comment: cool will do, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: https://codepen.io/lvl9d/pen/RwrKWwE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set the display property of **#nav-list** back to **flex** when switching to larger viewport, since it's already overrided when mobile navigation is toggled.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 760px){
  #nav-list {
    display: flex!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was a much needed simple solution. I wasn't aware of this value.